# Express Undefined Variable Inside app.get(...)

Tags: javascript, express

**THIS IS IN EXPRESS**
I defined the variable 
`const username = "a"`
`const password = "a"`
and then i redefined it with
`{username, password} = req.body`
(i had a form--this was /createaccount)
 then, an error popped up which was unexpected token '=' is this because username is not defined in `app.get(/createaccount...)`???

Comment: Can you paste the actual code? It should be easier for us to help you with the issue

Comment: wow. the second answer is good ``` ({username , password } = req.body); ```

Comment: @DeadWolf Please mark it as correct.

Comment: yes, i did @Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
let username = "a";
let password = "b";

({username , password } = req.body);
```

Since you have declared username and password and used destructuring in the next line you need to wrap the destructuring inside ();

Quoting from https://developer.mozilla.org/:

> The parentheses ( ... ) around the assignment statement are required
> when using object literal destructuring assignment without a
> declaration.